# Populate HorizontalScrollView dynamically with data (Images) from the server

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` which I want to populate with images that'll come from the server through a service. I'm unable to figure out how to integrate the said `HorizontalScrollView` with an adapter (maybe, `BaseAdapter`) and a layout, which the adapter will populate as the data will come in.

I want the `HorizontalScrollView` to have 10 images if server sends 10 image and 15, if the server sends 15 images.

In case of a `listview`, a cursor adapter or some other adapter can be used to populate the list dynamically. Is there any counterpart for `HorizontalScrollLView` which I can use?

Comment: `HorizontalScrollview` does not use an adapter just like `ScrollView` does not

Comment: You could simply make an ImageView for each image downloaded, and add them on-by-one to a LinearLayout inside the HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You should check out ViewPager. The Google example is pretty close to what you want to achieve

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html